# Xamarin.Forms: How to pass data from a Custom View to containing page with correct MVVM?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding

I am just learning Xamarin.Forms and MVVM (learning by doing), so please excuse my beginner's question:

I have a view **A** (a page) that calls a custom view **B**. **A** has view model **ModelA**, **B** has view model **ModelB**. User input in **B** (the custom view) is captured in the view model **ModelB** by data binding.

How do I pass this data to view model **ModelA** for further processing?

My first guess for a solution is to pass data by events: ModelB -> B -> (by XAML) -> A -> ModelA. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Did you try to declare the viewmodel B in the viewmodel A? And you can try give up the viewmodel B and just declare the data in the viewmodel A, the custom view don't have to get a viewmodel class.

Comment: Well, I try to implement Custom View B like a third-party view. So A / ModelA should not know about the internals of B.

Comment: I can't understand the third-party view you said. When I use a view which is from the nuget package such as syncfusion. I will bind the view's bindable property to the page's viewmodel instead of creating a viewmodel class for it.

Comment: And how do I then populate the views (Label, Picker etc.) within B? I think there must be a separate view model for B.

Comment: You can also bind it to the page's viewmodel. Did you check the official document about the relative binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I strictly separated the responsabilities of View **A** and Custom View **B**. Now less interaction is needed between **ModelA** and **ModelB**. In addidion I am using Two-Way Databinding to transfer resulting data back to **ModelA**.